# How do I connect to Google Service Account without a private key?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-api, public-key-encryption

I do know that in order to authenticate using Google Application Credentials, you get the JSON file from the Service Account and load the credentials:

`os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = '/path/to/my/jsonfile.json'`

When I opened the JSON file, it is formatted this way, with the private key and the private key id:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "project-name",
  "private_key_id": "...",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n...----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "client-email@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "client-id",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/doh-21%40doh-14.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
}
```

Instead of using the private key ID and the private key, is there a way to just use the public key to authenticate instead? How should I change the JSON file so that the public key ID and the public key credentials are added in?

Comment: Why do you want to connect without a private key? What's your pain point?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere It's a long story. Apparently, I've had people tell me they want reading access to the data but at the same time they don't want to go through the pain of adding them via IAM permissions nor do they want the JSON file with the private key to be publicly available nor do they want the data to be publicly accessible.

Comment: In your post, you published the link to the public key for your service account. One day we might be able to derive an RSA private key from a public key but there is no known (published) method today for keys larger than about 768 bits. Google RSA keys are 2048 bits. This [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_size) discusses some of the challenges.

Comment: FYI after your post edit: the public key link is still available in the post history. Don't worry, public keys are public and there is no security issue with leaking them today.

Comment: @SunnyLeague, your user want the data accessible, secure and private without taking time/effort to be authenticated with a secure manner? Did you ask them why them lock their door when they leave their house? Using key is boring, it's easier if it's always open!

Answer (score 2):

No absolutely not.

Service account authorization is used for server to server communication to access private user data. it is sometimes called "two-legged OAuth," or "2LO.".   They json key file is required to identify your application and the keys are needed for verification of your application and the creation of the authorization flow.

[service-account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)

API keys or public keys are only used for access public data.